# Angular 9 Customize environment option

Tags: angular

Angular 9 project

`environment.prod.ts`, for production build work `ng build --prod`, but for now I need to add a test environment with `ng build --test` and use `environment.test.ts` and deploy for manual testers.

`environment.test.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  test: true,
  host: 'http://11.111.111.111:8080/api/',
};
```

I add to `angular.json`

```
         "test": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "6kb",
              "maximumError": "10kb"
            }
          ]
        }
```

and

```
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "tradeshare:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "tradeshare:build:production"
        },
        "test": {
          "browserTarget": "tradeshare:build:test"
        }
      }
    },
```

and

```
    "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "tradeshare:serve"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "devServerTarget": "tradeshare:serve:production"
        },
        "test": {
          "devServerTarget": "tradeshare:serve:test"
        }
      }
    }
```

And result:

```
ng build --test
Unknown option: '--test'
```

How I can fix this error and assign an environment file replacement for `--test` option?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your package.json file and add below code there to add a build command to run test configuration.

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test-build": "ng build  --configuration test",
    ...
```

You can run the command like this: `npm run test-build`

Comment: it's a good alternative, but 2 different ways to build different environments

Comment: The command you need is `ng build  --configuration test`(on angular 12)  | you can also try `ng build  --configuration=development`, but to make it eaiser i'd put it in package.json that way i can just run it like any other npm command.

Comment: @Pavel if you think it solved your problem you can accept this as an answer.

Comment: I know but I search how to make `ng build --test`. Solution with npm current realization.